# apt-get is broken by unmet dependencies

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

This is apparently a very common issue, but I'm having trouble solving my particular problem from other questions. I'm on ubuntu 16.04.

I started by trying to install opencv using [this tutorial.](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) Starting out, I tried

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff-dev
```

and I get

```
kpierce@dw7mhal3:~$ sudo apt-get install libtiff-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libtiff5-dev' instead of 'libtiff-dev'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libtiff5-dev : Depends: libtiff5 (= 4.0.6-1) but 4.0.6-1ubuntu0.4 is to be installed
                Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Ok, so I have held broken packages, so I try to fix them:

```
sudo apt-get update –fix-missing
sudo dpkg –configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This doesn't enact any changes.

What can I do here?

Edit:

```
kpierce@dw7mhal3:~$ sudo apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     release v=16.04,o=CRAN,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=CRAN,c=
     origin cloud.r-project.org
 500 http://mirror.it.ubc.ca/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin mirror.it.ubc.ca
 500 http://mirror.it.ubc.ca/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin mirror.it.ubc.ca
 500 http://mirror.it.ubc.ca/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin mirror.it.ubc.ca
 500 http://mirror.it.ubc.ca/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin mirror.it.ubc.ca
 500 http://mirror.it.ubc.ca/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin mirror.it.ubc.ca
 500 http://mirror.it.ubc.ca/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin mirror.it.ubc.ca
 500 http://mirror.it.ubc.ca/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin mirror.it.ubc.ca
 500 http://mirror.it.ubc.ca/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin mirror.it.ubc.ca
Pinned packages:
kpierce@dw7mhal3:~$
```

Comment: I would check your sources - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libtiff5 shows 4.0.6-1ubuntu0.6 is what you should be offered (not 0.4) so either (a) you haven't updated (`sudo apt update`) your repository lists, (b) have non-official sources for 16.04, or (c) your chosen mirror is woefully out-of-date (and should be changed; https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors).  The '*you have broken packages*' also imply you've had issues before you ignored, I'd suggest fixing them.

Comment: For more assistance we'd likely need `apt-cache policy` for the information; as both are available.  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=zlib1g-dev for the other package mentioned)

Comment: @guiverc I'm fully updated and the mirror is almost fully up to date (1 day off in certain aspects) .. broken packages is the issue I guess. I cleaned out all of the lock files and am still getting nowhere. I updated with `apt-cache policy`